# Can I install ONE vscode server instead of one per user?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a server setup for my students and I really love the Remote Development Plugin. I setup all my students so they have one account each. It works almost flawlessly.

The caveat is that each student has a `.vscode-server` folder that uses roughly **600-700mb** of space.

Is there a way to install it globally so it only takes up one time 700mb instead of 30 times 700m?
Current solution is a lot of overhead data.

Answer (score 1):

i don't think it's supported. If you look into the contents of `.vscode-server`, you'll find 3 directories:

- `bin` -> Node server
- `data` -> User specific settings and logs
- `extensions` -> User extensions

Each user should have his own `data` and `extensions`, so the only thing that "can" be amortized is the `bin` directory. Unfortunately, nothing in the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) mention anything about it

To minimize the impact, you can ask the students to only download essential editor extensions (UI extensions, like themes, are stored on client side), and to regularly remove the cached extensions and logs:

```
$ rm -rf ~/.vscode-server/data/CachedExtensionVSIXs
$ rm -rf ~/.vscode-server/data/logs
```